# Nextjs TypeError: "Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined", after update to nextjs 12.1.0

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js

After update to Nextjs 12.1.0, when I call api via api route, the following error is returned. I'm using aws amplify.

[image]

The following error is returned in the CloudFront console:
[image]

My api route:

```
const handlerProducts = async (req: NextApiRequest, res:NextApiResponse) => {
const params = req.query;

try {
  const { data } = await axios.get(URL, {
    params,
  });

  res.status(200).send(data);
} catch (err: any) {
  res.status(500).end();
}};
```

What could be causing this problem?
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded next.js to `12.0.8` and it works again

While investigating possibly the same issue, I found https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/issues/2327

[zhenjie states on GitHub](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/issues/2327#issuecomment-1028456764): "Confirmed `12.0.8` works fine, and `12.0.9` does not work."

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I also used this solution